# Position of objects in image by output bitmap from CNN model

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

Do you guys have any tips in how i would be able to get the coordinates/segment every object seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlfBJ.jpg) by color.

I Would like the result to look something like this:  [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJaki.jpg), which is an edge detection output from the program ImageJ

Comment: My suggestion would be to get a better image if possible.

Comment: Would it not work with that ?

Comment: I don't know, as you haven't given any indication of what results you expect. Maybe you could add separate images showing what you expect from the first couple of *"cherries"*.

Comment: What is an object? Is it just the green or just the red or the combination of both?

Comment: I want to segment/ make a contour around each object that is colored red and green separately.

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/OCh8ylc

Comment: **OpenCV** `findContours()` would seem a good starting point. Try searching on Stack for a few samples, and come back if you get stuck.